# Open the attachment in the subheading in agenda view

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I am wondering if I can open the attachment which is attached to the father heading in agenda view. I think it will be very convenient to open as the way above. I really  do not want to attach the same file to all of the subheadings.

I have turned on the inheritance of the properties, but it seems like that the subheadings does not inherit the attachment properties.

Is there anyway to solve this problems?

Answer (score 1):

About my question, I finally found the solution which offered by org-attach.

Pressing `C-c C-a` in your father heading, you will see a list of org-attach options. At the bottom, the i command gives the function that is described as:

`Make children of the current entry inherit its attachment directory.`

After pressing i, everything will work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Property inheritance is not on by default, you need to enable if for specific properties.

If you set org-use-property-inheritance is to t, then "every property is inherited" as stated by the doc string.  If not, that's a bug you should report.